# combinatorics - pigeonhole principle - 2

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I've advanced a little with this question but I'm not sure that I'm in the right direction.

For any set $X$ with $n$ positive numbers, $n>5$, prove the existiance of subset $Y \subset X$ so that we can sum the elements of $Y$ with different signs (i.e. for $y \in Y$ we can add to our sum $y$ or $-y$) and the sum of the elements from Y will be multiple of $n^2$ ($n$ is the size of the original set - $X$).

I've noticed that the number of 'sums' that we can create is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}2^k$.
Using the binomial formula I've get that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}2^k = 3^n$, but I didn't advanced further.

Comment: Is $X$ a subset of the natural numbers? Integers? Real numbers? Complex numbers? Something else? Because if $X$ is _any_ finite set, then this doesn't make much sense (how do you add chairs and tables with different signs?)

Comment: There is a natural ring structure over chairs it's called chair chain.

Comment: OK. edited. thanks for the comment.

Comment: There are $2^n-1$ different non-empty subsets of $X$.  If $2^n-1 > n^2$ (which is true for $n \ge 5$), then two different non-empty subsets of $X$ must have the same sum modulo $n^2$.  Assign $+1$ to elements in only the first subset and $-1$ to elements in only the second subset.